# How to get the overall status in SQL even if one record is missing?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT 'EMPLOYEE TABLE' TABLE ,
   CASE WHEN ROLL_NO IN 'MISSING' THEN 'FAIL' ELSE 'PASS' END AS STATUS 
FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE;
```

EMPLOYEE_TABLE Table:

```
employee    roll_no
---------------------
  A           E
  B           F
  C           MISSING
  D           MISSING
```

Output:

```
TABLE               STATUS
----------------------------
EMPLOYEE TABLE      FAIL
EMPLOYEE TABLE      FAIL
EMPLOYEE TABLE      PASS
EMPLOYEE TABLE      PASS
```

Expected output (to be only 1 row with either 'PASS' or 'FAIL' )

```
TABLE               STATUS
----------------------------
EMPLOYEE TABLE      FAIL
```

If any one record is missing then I want the overall status to be 'FAIL' or else I should get 'PASS'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT 'EMPLOYEE TABLE' TABLE, 
CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * from EMPLOYEE_TABLE WHERE roll_no IN ('MISSING'))
THEN 'FAIL' ELSE 'PASS' END AS STATUS
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: This is Oracle. Add `FROM DUAL`.

Comment: The idea is good. I would make this `WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE WHERE roll_no IN ('MISSING'))` though to speed this up.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
    'EMPLOYEE TABLE' TABLE, 
    MIN(CASE WHEN ROLL_NO IN 'MISSING' THEN 'FAIL' ELSE 'PASS' END) AS STATUS 
FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE
GROUP BY 'EMPLOYEE TABLE';
```

`MIN` will order alphabetically your results for the status column. Since you only return fail or pass, as soon as there's fail in the records of a given employee table, then it will show fail. If there's no fail then it will show pass.

I grouped by employee table but it's unclear to me what it represents - it might have to be changed.